# Sending more than a file to a puppet client

Tags: puppet, puppetmaster, puppet-agent

How I must configure a "init.pp" file for sending more than a file in the same class?
What I have done is this:

```
class nagios {
        file { ['/usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/']:
                path => '/usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/',
                ensure => directory,
                notify => Service['nrpe'],
                source => ["puppet:///modules/mymodule/check_mem.sh",
                           'puppet:///modules/mymodule/check_mountpoint.sh'],
                sourceselect => all,
        }
        service { 'nrpe':
                ensure => 'running',
                enable => true,
        }
}
```

What I'm trying is sending two different files to the same remote folder and then restart service.

However, when I run puppet at client, I get these errors:

```
[...]
Error: Could not set 'file' on ensure: Is a directory - (/usr/lib64/nagios/plugins20170306-28992-j54k6x, /usr/lib64/nagios/plugins) at 153:/etc/puppet/modules/mymodule/manifests/init.pp
[...]
Error: /Stage[main]/Nagios/File[/usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/]/ensure: change from directory to file failed: Could not set 'file' on ensure: Is a directory - (/usr/lib64/nagios/plugins20170306-28992-j54k6x, /usr/lib64/nagios/plugins) at 153:/etc/puppet/modules/mymodule/manifests/init.pp
```

Where is my mistake?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The `sourceselect` parameter only affects recursive directory copies. For single files, you need multiple `file` resources, as in that case, only the first file will be copied.

> Alternately, when serving directories recursively, multiple sources can be combined by setting the sourceselect attribute to all.

([Source](https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/latest/type.html#file-attribute-source))

Your second problem is that you tell Puppet to ensure that the target is a directory. In that case, giving a source file doesn't make any sense - you can't save a file as a directory. You would need to set it to `file` or `present`.

Re your comment: Something like this should work:

```
    file { ['/usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_mem.sh']:
            ensure => "file",
            notify => Service['nrpe'],
            source => "puppet:///modules/mymodule/check_mem.sh",
    }

    file { ['/usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_mountpoint.sh']:
            ensure => "file",
            notify => Service['nrpe'],
            source => "puppet:///modules/mymodule/check_mountpoint.sh",
    }
```

Comment: But I think there can only be one "file" resource in a class... so if I have created a "nagios" class, in that class I can just send a file, aren't you?

Comment: No, there can be multiple file resources in a class, but they all need to have different names. Usually, I just name them after the target file names and Puppet uses this as the default value for `target`.

Comment: How do you that? I'm new in Puppet...

Comment: Please see my edit:

Comment: Thaaaaaanksss!!!